# Changing the Visual Range of chart in LightningChart JS?

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I have range selector in my chart and would like to reflect the changes in chart based on the range selected. Range includes the start date and end date of the chart.

So, chart should show values within that range on the x -axis.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the range of an axis with [axis.setInterval](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.2.2/classes/axis.html#setinterval).

So if you want to have your X-axis start from 10 and end at 556.

```js
series.axisX.setInterval(10, 556)
```

Comment: Can I use a navigator panel kinda thing to move for rest of the data

Comment: I don't understand the question and you should post the question with more information as a separate question, not as a comment.